# A column get false data when trying to get data using Inner Join in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I've two table in my database.

1. **Transaction Table**

   [image]
2. **M_Trans Table**

[image]

And I've set query like this

```
select distinct inv.transId as Order ID,
sfc.nofaktur as Faktur, 
inv.amount as PPn,
inv.salesId

from Transaction inv
    inner join M_Trans sfc on sfc.invoice=inv.invoice
where (
         DATEPART(yy, inv.date) = '2018'
         AND DATEPART(mm, inv.date) = '2'
      )         

      order by sfc.nofaktur asc
```

But it doesn't give what I need, my Excepetation *result* is like this:`
[image]

and the *result* of the query is like this :
(data in salesId isn't true)
[image]

**How do I can fix the query so I can get data that I need?**

Thanks

Comment: MySQL is not Microsoft SQL server. What exactly U use?

Comment: `inner join M_Trans efa on sfc.invoice=inv.invoice` - What's `sfc`?

Comment: how is this query working? none of the table is gives `sfc` as alias but you are using it `sfc.invoice`

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've update the question. I'm using SQL Server

Comment: sorry, it was typo. That is not efa, the true alias is 'sfc'

Comment: do you have a 1-to-1 relation on invoice number in the 2 tables ? If yes, this is strange...

Comment: The query is OK, there must be some data that you are not seeing in your tables. Remove the distinct and filter by transID = 3 to see where the problem is.

Comment: Based on the sample data you provided (which has no `inv.date` so I left the `WHERE` clause out), your query works fine. [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d8aa7/4)

Comment: @ThomasG I can't find out the relation between both of them because they give limited access, but If I'm not wrong it was 1 - N (Transaction - M_Trans)